# Applescript find and replace text in multiples files

Tags: text, replace, find, applescript, textedit

I've multiple text files made with TextEdit in a folder. I want to find and replace a same string in all of them using AppleScript.

I'm a total newbie to AppleScript language. I've just made very simple script with it.
Would you please suggest me the code?

### Thanks.

Comment: I've just google it and made few attempts with what I found. None of them worked for me but probably because I'm not an expert of AS code, so I need really to start from scratch.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to request free work. Many users will be happy to help once you have posted your code to demonstrate that you have put some effort into the problem. Don't worry if it works or if it is "good".

Comment: Thanks, I beg your pardon. I'll try to make some more deep attempts. Thanks again.

Comment: @Neuran add your solution as an Answer and accept it. Then remove the update from yoru question. This will inform users that the question is solved and they do not need click into it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my problems.

```
set myFiles to (choose file with multiple selections allowed)

display dialog "Text to replace" default answer ""
   set textToReplace to text returned of result

display dialog "Text to insert" default answer ""
   set textToInsert to text returned of result

repeat with aFile in myFiles
   set myData to do shell script "cat " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
   set newData to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of myData & " | sed 's/" & textToReplace & "/" & textToInsert & "/g' > " & quoted form of (aFile's POSIX path)
end repeat
```